# Not getting back any columns of the joined tables - typeorm

Tags: nestjs-typeorm

Is there a different way to join systemVars on gateways?

I only get back gateway columns.

```
    const qb = this.gatewaysRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('g')
      .leftJoinAndSelect(
        SystemVars,
        'sv',
        'RIGHT(sv.value, 8) = RIGHT(g.gatewayID, 8)'
      )
      .leftJoinAndSelect('sv.system', 's')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('s.organisation', 'o')
      .leftJoinAndSelect(
        Organisation,
        'c0',
        'o.createdByOrganisation = c0.organisationId'
      );
```

I was expecting back columns from the 4 joined entities

I believe the issue is from the first join on systemVars